# JQuery .each() backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reverse

I'm using JQuery to select some elements on a page and then move them around in the DOM. The problem I'm having is I need to select all the elements in the reverse order that JQuery naturally wants to select them. For example:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the li items and use the .each() command on them but I want to start with Item 5, then Item 4 etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 732, accepted):

```
$($("li").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Should be important to note that the index is not reversed, so if you are only wanting to do the last three, for instance, you cannot expect `<li>Item 5</li>` to have an index of 0.

Comment: to David Andres: may be you forgot to add additional $() before li. I did this mistake and received "undefined func".

Comment: @DavidAndres: You missed the `.get()` which turns the jQuery wrapped array into an ordinary JS array. The JS array has `.reverse()`.

Comment: Caution:  `Array.reverse()` both modifies the array **in place** and returns the reversed array. So this solution actually relies upon $().get() returning a new array, and _not_ a reference to some internal jQuery or DOM array. Probably a safe bet within the confines of this example. Caveat Coder.

Answer (score 428):

I present you with the cleanest way ever, in the form of the world's smallest jquery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

Usage:

```
$('jquery-selectors-go-here').reverse().each(function () {
    //business as usual goes here
});
```

-All credit to Michael Geary in his post here: http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg04261.html

Answer (score 65):

You can do

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};
```

followed by

```
$(selector).reverse().each(...)
```

Comment: This approach was originally proposed by John Resig (jQuery developer) on the [jQuery mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg04272.html).

Answer (score 24):

Here are different options for this:

**First**: without jQuery:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
var contents = [].map.call(lis, function (li) {
    return li.innerHTML;
}).reverse().forEach(function (content, i) {
    lis[i].innerHTML = content;
});
```

#### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/66/)

... and with jQuery:

You can use this:

```
$($("ul > li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + (++i));
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/)

**Another** way, using also jQuery with [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$("ul > li").reverse().each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + (++i));
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/1/).

**One more** alternative is to use the `length` (count of elements matching that selector) and go down from there using the `index` of each iteration. Then you can use this:

```
var $li = $("ul > li");
$li.each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + ($li.length - i));
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/64/)

**One more**, kind of related to the one above:

```
var $li = $("ul > li");
$li.text(function (i) {
    return 'Item ' + ($li.length - i);
});
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/65/)**

Answer (score 14):

I prefer creating a reverse plug-in eg

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = function(fn) {       
   var i = this.length;

   while(i--) {
       fn.call(this[i], i, this[i])
   }
};
```

Usage eg:

```
$('#product-panel > div').reverse(function(i, e) {
    alert(i);
    alert(e);
});
```

Comment: I like this idea/code too, but it doesn't return a chainable object (that is reversed) like the higher-voted answers :) Still, definitely a good method for the way it's setup

Comment: You are right. Not chainable so not a valid plugin. Have improved the code slightly though, moving the decrementer into the condition.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to save method into jQuery.fn you can use

```
[].reverse.call($('li'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Needed to do a reverse on $.each so i used Vinay idea:

```
//jQuery.each(collection, callback) =>
$.each($(collection).get().reverse(), callback func() {});
```

worked nicely, thanks

Comment: This isn't right; this should just be `$.each(collection.reverse(), ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot iterate backwards with the jQuery each function, but you can still leverage jQuery syntax.

Try the following:

```
//get an array of the matching DOM elements   
var liItems = $("ul#myUL li").get();

//iterate through this array in reverse order    
for(var i = liItems.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
  //do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found `Array.prototype.reverse` unsuccessful with objects, so I made a new jQuery function to use as an alternative: `jQuery.eachBack()`. It iterates through as the normal `jQuery.each()` would, and stores each key into an array. It then reverses that array and performs the callback on the original array/object in the order of the reversed keys.

```
jQuery.eachBack=function (obj, callback) {
    var revKeys=[]; $.each(obj,function(rind,rval){revKeys.push(rind);}); 
    revKeys.reverse();
    $.each(revKeys,function (kind,i){
        if(callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]) === false) {    return false;}
    });
    return obj;
}   
jQuery.fn.eachBack=function (callback,args) {
    return jQuery.eachBack(this, callback, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is like *JoeChung*'s answer with the difference that by this code you can **just use the container element (`ul`):**

```js
$($("ul").children().get().reverse()).each(function(i, elm) {

    console.log($(elm).text()) 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try

```
var arr = [].reverse.call($('li'))
arr.each(function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score -2):

I think u need

```
.parentsUntill()
```

Comment: Why do you think that? And how would you use it?