# how to iterate elements in reverse order in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i'm new to jquery.I'd like to know how to iterate form elements in reverse order in jquery using each()?
Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

Comment: @BoltClock. Then why didn't you close it (two years ago?)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try this

```
$($("input").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 20):

```
$($("input").get().reverse()).each(function() { 
   //function body here
});
```

The `.get().reverse()` returns the reversed array of all your elements
You can then use `each()` to return each individual element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to the site, to format your code blocks simply indent each line by four spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more.

Answer (score 12):

I use a similar method as above, but shorter, define a jQuery reverse function to be the same as the reverse function of an array:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

now you can use it like this:

```
$('img').reverse().each(function(){ /* do something */ });
```

Comment: This works in every case where I had to use this, but does anybody know why this isn't implemented in jQuery by default?

Comment: Well, this method is not required that often by developers. And jQuery has plugins support. If don't have something, create.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet

```
$.each(  $( $('input').get().reverse() )  , function(){ /* ... */ });
```

Comment: reverse is not a built-in jQuery command, your answer results in "TypeError: $(...).reverse is not a function"

Answer (score 3):

I prefer creating a reverse plug-in eg

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = function(fn) {

   var i = this.length;

   while(i) {
        i--;
        fn.call(this[i], i, this[i])
   }
};
```

Usage eg:

```
$('#product-panel > div').reverse(function(i, e) {
    alert(i);
    alert(e);
});
```