# jQuery $.each() reverse/backward iteration

Tags: jquery, each

I'm parsing an array using `$.each()`, but inside it, I'm using `.splice()` method, so I need to iterate backward. Is it possible ?

```
var store = [...];
//...
var rules = [...];
//...
$.each(store, function(index, element) { // This loop needs to iterate backward
    $.each(rules, function(index2, rule) {
        if (element.id == rule.id) {
            store.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

**WARN :**

- I don't want to reverse the array, it wouldn't be the same behavior.
- Also I know I could use `for`, I just want to know if it's achievable using `$.each`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards

Comment: Nop, I've seen this post, it's using a `.reverse()` on the array. Please, fully read the question.

Comment: I fail to see why can't you just use hash here (then filter based on this hash).

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop To use correctly `.splice`, you have to iterate backward. And `$.each()` isn't basically.

Comment: Why can you use a simple `for` loop?

Comment: I could as I wrote in the question. And I finally did.^^ But I wanted to know if it was doable using `$.each()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(store.reverse(), function(index, element) { // This loop iterate backward
[...]
```

This works, it's the same as this post [jquery-each-backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496795/how-to-iterate-elements-in-reverse-order-in-jquery/4496814). But the point here is, you're applying this over the `store`.

Comment: This method of reversing works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use $.each but you'd have to decrement the indice variables (index, index2) as you did.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each()` itself cannot be iterated backwards as there is no modifier for it.  The input it takes is from a selector.  which can be converted into an array.  Then `$.each()` iterates forwards by index (0,1,2,... and so on).

The only way to reverse flow is to either `Array.reverse()` or find an iterator loop that does so.  You can also build a recursion function that serves your purpose.  But all these options are outside the limitation of `$.each()`

Here are options from iteration loops to consider:

-> **for loop (*reverse*)**

```
var value = 10;
for (var i = value; i; i--){
    console.log(i);
    //bonus
    //return back to a proper flow is to add the whole value it
    console.log(value + i);
}
```

-> **while loop (*reverse*)**:

```
var X=9,Y=X;
while (--Y) {
    console.log(Y);
    //will only stop at 1 since while cannot return a falsy value
    //0 is considered a falsy value, and is nullified from the loop
}
```

Options to consider to reverse array iteration:

-> **`Array.reverse().forEach()`**

As my late mentor once said, `There is more than one way to carve an elephant from stone.`  This site exists because many people have creative ways to solve issues.  Unfortunately, there isn't anything built into `$.each()` that will run backwards stand-alone, hence people resorting to other means (some of which are mentioned above).  Im sorry this isnt a satisfactory "yes" answer to the question, but hopefully explains why `$.each()` can only loop forward.  If this is me making my own solution it would be this:

```
var loopy=(value,output)=>{
    for(var i = value; i; i--){
        output.call(this,{
           index:{
               forward:()=>value-i,
               reverse:()=>i-1
           },
           count:{
               forward:()=>1+value-1,
               reverse:()=>i
           }
        })
    }
}

loopy(10, i=>console.log( i.index.forward() ))
```

The function above allows you to have options ranging whole counts and index counts.  This is similar to how `Array.forEach()` works except youre outputting an object and its values per iteration.  I use a function similar to this to fetch object's values, keys, and indexes.