# javascript: get object item in real order

Tags: javascript, object

i need to get real order of simple javascript abject, but i get incorrect answer from this code:

```
var Obj={"x":"z", "2":"a", "1":"b"};
for(i in Obj)
    document.write(Obj[i]+"<br>");
```

I expect to see `z`, `a`, `b` as answer, but i get `b`, `a`, `z`
See the code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/gpP7m/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There's no guaranteed order in object keys iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order

If you need one, use an array of key/value elements :

```
var obj=[
   {key:"x", value:"z"},
   {key:"2", value:"a"}
];

for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) document.write(obj[i].value+'<br>');
```

On a modern browser (not IE8), you can do :

```
document.write(obj.map(function(kv){ return kv.value }).join('<br>'));
```

(which doesn't do exactly the same but probably does what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Check for below sample too

```
var data1 = {"x":"z", "2":"a", "1":"b"};
var arr = [];
var i=0;
$.each(data1,function(index,value) {
   arr[i++] = value;
});
var len = arr.length-1;

while( len>=0 ) {
   if( arr[len] !== undefined ) {
      alert(arr[len]);
   }
   len--; 
}
```

and referece link is [Reverse object in jQuery.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838630/reverse-object-in-jquery-each)

And fiddle update http://jsfiddle.net/gpP7m/3/