# jQuery: Reverse the value in each function

Tags: jquery, each, reverse

I created dropdown and get value from the response, but here is the issue, reverse.config have two value:1 ,2.  now I have to print 2, 1 which I am trying to print, I tried using reverse(), but its not working.

```
jQuery.each(response.config, function (index,value) {
    var select = value.label + '<select class="configurable"  name="' + index + '" >';
    jQuery.each(value.values, function (key, opt) {
        select += '<option value="' + opt.value_index + '">' + opt.label + '</option>>'
    });
    select += '</select>';
    jQuery("#newProduct").append(select);
});
```

Comment: Try `value = response.config[response.config.length - index - 1]`

Comment: response.config is Array or Object ?

Comment: @JayVaghasiya object

Comment: @User863, no its not working

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR Post what have you tried and sample response.config

Comment: @User863 I just replace my 'value' to your value = response.config[response.config.length - index - 1]

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR Please provide response example JSON

Comment: @JayVaghasiya https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vV1EwHqzjO1RZHkpQ6KGR19qb5jxgRVL/view?usp=sharing , I am working on Magento and response.config provides me configuration option of the product

Comment: I guess this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838642/5513005

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR From your Object there are 2 keys 93 and 141 so you want 141 and 93, right ?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR can you add your response.config output in a question

Comment: @JayVaghasiya yes

Comment: @NegiRox, I already share screenshot link in comment

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR answer updated. see below example

Answer (score 1):

value.values is your object. you can get your keys using **Object.keys(value.values)** then reverse it now you have keys in reversed order. iterate over it and get you object base on reversed keys array.
According to your json asuming below json is same as your format.

```
var json={
  "41": {
    "values": [
      {
        "valeu_index": 1,
        "label": "op1"
      },
      {
        "valeu_index": 2,
        "label": "op2"
      }
    ],
    "label": "lbl1"
  },
  "91": {
    "values": [
      {
        "valeu_index": 1,
        "label": "opt1"
      },
      {
        "valeu_index": 2,
        "label": "opt2"
      }
    ],
    "label": "lbl2"
  }
}
```

```js
var values1=[{valeu_index:1,label:"op1"},{valeu_index:2,label:"op2"}]
var values2=[{valeu_index:1,label:"opt1"},{valeu_index:2,label:"opt2"}]
var response={};
response[41]={values:values1,label:'lbl1'};
response[91]={values:values2,label:"lbl2"};
console.log(response);
 var select = '<select class="configurable"  name="config" >';
var reversed=Object.keys(response).reverse(); 

        $.each(reversed, function (key, opt) {
                var obj=response[opt];
                var select = obj.label+'<select class="configurable"  name="config" >';
                debugger;
                $.each(obj.values,function(i,o){
                select += '<option value="' + o.value_index + '">' + o.label + '</option>>'
                });
                 select += '</select>';
            $("#newProduct").append(select);

            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='newProduct'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use reverse on Array

```
var t = {
  93: { id: 3 },
  141: { id: 2 }
}

jQuery.each(Object.keys(t).reverse(), function( index, value ) {
  console.log(t[value]);
});
```