# jquery: reverse an order

Tags: jquery, each, reverse

How can I reverse an order with jquery?

I tried with the suggestion like this but it won't work!

```
$($(".block-item").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/).

I want the boxed to be rearranged like this,

```
18
17
16
etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: HELPFUL QUESTION : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a container around the list, it's a little easier:

`$("#container").append($(".block-item").get().reverse());`

http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/12/

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

```
$($(".block-item").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).text(++i);
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/90/).
Second [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yw4mdc3/) (changing the DOM elements positioning).

**Another** way, using also jQuery with [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$(".block-item").reverse().each(function (i) {
    $(this).text(++i);
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/91/).
Second [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9rtcne5/) (changing the DOM elements positioning).

**One more** alternative is to use the `length` (count of elements matching that selector) and go down from there using the `index` of each iteration. Then you can use this:

```
var nr_of_divs = $(".block-item").length;
$(".block-item").each(function (i) {
    $(this).text(nr_of_divs - i);
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/92/)
Second [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rd1qeo5e/) (changing the DOM elements positioning).

**One more**, kind of related to the one above:

```
var nr_of_divs = $(".block-item").length;
$(".block-item").text(function (i) {
    return nr_of_divs - i;
});
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/93/)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129036/discussion-between-seika85-and-sergio).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working. Just choose jQuery framework on the left hand.

```
 $($(".block-item").get().reverse()).each(function() {
     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this be what you are looking for?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/reverseorder

Comment: yes it is. I thought there are other simpler methods than using this plugin. thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function disp(divs) {
      var a = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a.push(divs[i].innerHTML);
      }
    alert(a);
    }

    disp( $("div.block-item").get().reverse() );
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BhTEN/10/)

Comment: **note:** `Array.reverse` has been around since JavaScript 1.1.