# Is there an inbuilt way to use JQuery's .each() in reverse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery .each() backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

What is the easiest way to use `.each()` in reverse? At the moment I am doing this:

```
var temp = [];

$("#nav a").each(function()
{
    temp.push($(this));
});

temp.reverse();
for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
    var a = temp[i];

    // Work with a.
}
```

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
$("#nav a").reverse().each(function()
{
    // Work with $(this).

});
```

The context is that I have a collection of elements using `float: right` which displays them in reverse order and I want to iterate over them from left to right like normal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards

Comment: @JonFriskics That'll work, thanks - voting to close my question :)

Comment: Great question to which I believe the answer is "no".  Some genius needs to do a small add-on package to jQuery to supply all the obvious functional programming primitives ... if there is one already somebody plz call me a dolt and name it :-)

Comment: [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
$($("#nav a").get().reverse()).each(function() { 
     //..........
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't take credit for this because I saw it somewhere else here on SO but I think this should help; add the functionality to jQuery's prototype like so:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse
```

Then use it as indicated above:

```
$('#nav a').reverse(); // returns a reversed array of elements
```

Hope this helps :)