# How to flip index of jquery's each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery .each() backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

I am using this code to show each div -> this with a delay an an animation:

```
$.fn.slideDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: 0
        }, 2000);
        delay += 1000;
    });
};
```

Works well so far... the only Problem i got is that i need to start with the last index not the first one. Which means the last div gets animated first then the beforelast and so on until the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically the following should work:

```
$.fn.slideDelay = function() {
    var len = this.length,
        delay = (len - 1) * 1000;

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: 0
        }, 2000);
        delay -= 1000;
    });
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/q4cGP/

Comment: To reverse the delays of three elements (`0 - 1000 - 2000`), I think you'd have to start with `(len - 1) * 1000`. Currently, in case of 3 elements you start with 3000.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, you're right. I forgot about the indexing. Now it should be fine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the collection...

```
collection = Array.prototype.reverse.call(collection);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHdDU/).

Answer (score 1):

Just retrieve the array from your jQuery object and reverse it:

```
var items = jQuery(this).get();
items.reverse();
jQuery.each(items, function() {.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the delay with a function like this:

```
$.fn.slideDelay = function(){
    var max = this.length - 1;
    return this.each(function(i){
        $(this).delay((max - i) * 1000).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: 0
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```