# jquery: iterate children() in reverse

Tags: jquery

I need to iterate over jquery child elements in reverse:

```
$("#parent").children().each(function() {
  # do stuff
})
```

but in reverse.

I have seen the use of reverse() with get()

```
$($("li").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

but don't seem able to make it   work with children().

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .each() backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same strategy as before:

```
$($("#parent").children().get().reverse()).each(function() {
      # do stuff
})
```

Or slightly more neatly:

```
[].reverse.call($("#parent").children()).each(function() {
      # do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

$("#parent").children().reverse().each(function () {
});
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg04261.html)

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this?  With the edit to add the step of copying the "reverse" method from the array prototype to the jQuery "fn" object, this should work just fine.

Comment: Moreover, this is how jQuery itself does it (see e.g. `$.sort` in  the sources).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$.each( $("#parent").children().get().reverse(), function(){
   // whatever..
} );
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/mPsep/

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$($("li").children().get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/maxzA/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:SEE http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$($("#parent > li").get().reverse()).each(function() {
  # do stuff
})
```