# Get id of ul and li from bottom to top in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

now i am using jquery to get ids of ul and li from top to bottom .but i cant able to get  it from bottom to top . iam using the following code

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        function next_click()
        {
        alert("next");
        var toHighlight = jQuery('.current').next().length > 0 ? jQuery('.current').next() : jQuery('#men_shirt li').first();
        jQuery('.current').removeClass('current');
        toHighlight.addClass('current');
        $('#men_shirt ul li').each(function(i)
        {
           var iid=$(this).attr('id'); 
           alert("sdfsdf"+iid);
        });

        var a=jQuery('li').hasClass('current');
        alert(a);

        if(a=='style')
        {
        set_menuselected('Style');
        }
        } 

</script>
```

Please advise on this

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle and explain bit more

Answer (score 1):

Use `.get().reverse()` See [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

```
$.each('#men_shirt ul li').get().reverse(),function(i)//use get.reverse method()
{
   var iid=$(this).attr('id'); 
   alert("sdfsdf"+iid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend jQuery with the reverse method:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

And then:

```
$('#men_shirt ul li').reverse().each(function() {
    ...
});
```