# reverse traversing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have a structure like this

```
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">10-Step Courses</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/10-steps-insecurity-relationships" class="purple-color">10 Steps to Overcome Insecurity in Relationships</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/10-steps-public-speaking" class="purple-color">10 Steps to Powerful Public Speaking</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/10-steps-self-esteem" class="purple-color">10 Steps to Solid Self Esteem</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Addiction Help</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/chocolate-addiction" class="purple-color">Chocolate Addiction</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/alcohol-abuse" class="purple-color">Diminish Alcohol Abuse</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/gambling-addiction" class="purple-color">Gambling Addiction</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/alcohol" class="purple-color">Stay Off Alcohol</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/obsessive-thoughts" class="purple-color">Stop Obsessive Thoughts</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Alternative Cancer Treatments</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/stay-positive" class="purple-color">Cancer - Stay Positive</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Bad Habits</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/lip-biting" class="purple-color">Lip Biting</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/nail-biting" class="purple-color">Stop Nail Biting</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Clinical Hypnotherapy</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/noise-sensitivity" class="purple-color">Noise Sensitivity</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Communication Skills</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/meeting-people" class="purple-color">Meeting People</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/speaking-groups" class="purple-color">Speaking Clearly</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Customer Service</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/general/customer-service" class="purple-color">Feedback from our customers</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Depression Self Help</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/depression-treatment" class="purple-color">Full Depression Treatment</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/managing-bipolar-disorder" class="purple-color">Managing Bipolar Disorder</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Emotional Intelligence</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/be-kinder" class="purple-color">Be Kinder</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/dealing-guilt" class="purple-color">Dealing with Guilt</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/jealousy" class="purple-color">Overcome Jealousy</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Fears and Phobias</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/dentist" class="purple-color">Dental Phobia</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/driving-test" class="purple-color">Driving Test</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-bridges" class="purple-color">Fear of Bridges</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-driving" class="purple-color">Fear of Driving</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-failure" class="purple-color">Fear of Failure</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-flying" class="purple-color">Fear of Flying</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-heights" class="purple-color">Fear of Heights</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/travel" class="purple-color">Fear of Travel</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/hayfever-relief" class="purple-color">Fear of Water</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-of-women" class="purple-color">Fear Of Women</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/singers-nerves" class="purple-color">Musicians &amp; Singers Nerves</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/fear-anxiety" class="purple-color">Overcome Fear &amp; Anxiety</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/claustrophobia" class="purple-color">Overcoming Claustrophobia</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/performance-anxiety" class="purple-color">Performance Anxiety</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/panic-attacks" class="purple-color">Stop Panic Attacks</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Fun Hypnosis</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/cloud-nine" class="purple-color">Cloud Nine</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/happy-days" class="purple-color">Happy Days</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading">Health Issues</div><div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/essential-tremor" class="purple-color">Essential Tremor</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/migraines" class="purple-color">Get Rid of Migraines</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/hayfever-relief" class="purple-color">Hayfever Relief</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/healing" class="purple-color">Healing Power Hypnosis</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/improve-posture" class="purple-color">Improve Posture</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/prepare-surgery" class="purple-color">Prepare for Surgery</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/restless-legs" class="purple-color">Restless Legs Syndrome</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/teeth-grinding" class="purple-color">Teeth Grinding</a></div>
<div class="spacedlinkwrap"><a href="/testimonials/wart-treatment" class="purple-color">Wart Treatment</a></div>
```

and this class name is my category :`spacedlinkboldwrap cat-heading` and its subcategory is `spacedlinkwrap` .Now i want to track user's click with its category name...but i am not getting in this structure.

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate of [JQuery .each() backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards), based on the title. As for the body of the question: it's really not clear what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: Is that a vertical menu? Or simply a link?

Comment: there is jQuery 1.4 so plz code w.r.t it.

Comment: No its not menu and all that.Simply i want to like this...example:
suppose user click on this "Diminish Alcohol Abuse" text then i want to get its parent means category name that is : "10-Step Courses"

Comment: The title and body of the question really don't match up too well.  Could you edit and clarify the question?

Comment: sorry for my bad structure plz copy and paste it in your IDE and apply source formatting and check it. is this possible to traverse reverse html tag using javascript DOM

Comment: @user3686800 Next time you ask a question with code, you should `copy and paste it in your IDE and apply source formatting`. This is the least you should do to help people who are trying to help you in their free time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery `.prevAll`:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rLQdv/***

*Example Code*:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $p = $(this).parent();
    var cat = $p.prevAll(".cat-heading").html();
    alert(cat);
});
```

*From this ref: http://api.jquery.com/prevall/*

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .prevAll() method searches through the predecessors of these elements
>   in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements; the elements are returned in order beginning with the
>   closest sibling.

**Notice the last line**: "*elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling"*

So, the code `$p.prevAll(".cat-heading").html()` will get the content of the first matched element which is the closest to the target anchor .

**Edit**:

As per your comment somewhere above, you are using jQuery 1.4; so just replace `.on("click"..` syntax with `.click(..` syntax. Or `.bind("click"..` syntax.

Comment: hey suppose i have one javascript variable that has html tag like <p>hi</p> and i want only text hi from it. how can i?

Comment: @user3686800: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/98avj/