# how to iterate loop from last index in $.each jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible I can get outputs : five four three two one

Here is my example Code

```
 var arr = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
```

//now i am getting Outputs: one two three four five

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
    $.each(arr.reverse(), function (index, value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```