# FadeOut menu onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I give up. After trying to google and changing my code. I'm going to ask this here. I have a click function `.navTrigger` which displays my nav menu's `li` one after another. This is working like it should.

Only when I click on the `.navTrigger` again I would like to have it `fadeOut` again (It would be awesome if it could be with a delay again). I just can't get my head around how to get this working? (probably pretty simple)...

Here is my code:

```
$('.navTrigger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var delay = 1000;
    $('nav ul > li a').each(function() {
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
        delay += 400;
    });
});
```

I have tried replacing `toggleClass` with `addClass` and then add

```
if ($('.navTrigger').hasClass('active')) {
    var delay = 1000;
    $('nav ul > li a').each(function() {
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
        delay += 400;
    });
} else {
    var delay = 1000;
    $('nav ul > li a').each(function() {
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeOut(500);
        delay += 400;
    });
}
```

But yeah, that didn't work either... any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're second snippet seems like it was almost right.

I've not seen your HTML structure but you should be able to switch the functions around and also add and remove the `active` class:

```js
$('.navTrigger').click(function(){

var delay = 1000;

if ($('.navTrigger').hasClass('active')){

    $('nav ul > li a').each(function(){
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeOut(500);
       delay += 400;
    });

    $('.navTrigger').removeClass('active');

} else {

    $('nav ul > li a').each(function(){
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
       delay += 400;
    });

    $('.navTrigger').addClass('active');
}

});
```

```css
nav ul > li a {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="navTrigger">Menu</button>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```

You could also reverse the fade out using the answer to this [StackOverflow Answer by Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394050/9019817):

```js
$('.navTrigger').click(function(){

var delay = 1000;

if ($('.navTrigger').hasClass('active')){

    $($('nav ul > li a').get().reverse()).each(function() {
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeOut(500);
       delay += 400;
    });

    $('.navTrigger').removeClass('active');

} else {

    $('nav ul > li a').each(function(){
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
       delay += 400;
    });

    $('.navTrigger').addClass('active');
}

});
```

```css
nav ul > li a {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="navTrigger">Menu</button>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This. Is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in click function  `$(this).toggleClass('active');`

```
$('.navTrigger').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('active');
if ($('.navTrigger').hasClass('active')){
    var delay = 1000;
        $('nav ul > li a').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(500);
            delay += 400;
    });
} else {
    var delay = 1000;
        $('nav ul > li a').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(delay).fadeOut(500);
            delay += 400;
    });
}


});
```