# Invert count for children inside a div

Tags: jquery, count

I'm using the next function to count every item inside a div and echo the index number for each.

Is there a way to achieve the exact same but starting from the biggest number to the smallest? Sort of flip what's in here

Thanks in advance

```
$(function() {
  $(".grid").each(function() {

      $(this).find('.num').each(function(i) {
      $(this).text(++i);
      $(this).text(function (i, n) {
   var result = Number(n) + 0;
   if ( result < 10 ) {
       return "0" + result + ".";
   } else {
       return result + ".";
   }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to implement the native array [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method as a jQuery method, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5386150/519413), in order to reverse the order of the elements before you iterate through them.

Also note that your `text()` logic is much more complicated than it needs to be. You're setting a value which is immediately overwritten, adding `0` for no purpose and converting values which are already numerical to Number. You can simply use `i` directly and use `slice()` to pad a leading `0` to it.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

jQuery($ => {
  $('.grid').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).find('.num').reverse().text(i => `00${i + 1}.`.slice(-3));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="num"></span>
</div>
```